# What's the difference between a file server and a non file-server OS?

Tags: file-sharing, file-server

In my current Windows Vista install (as well as other Window's installs), I can share files by sharing folders and having public directories.  What's the difference between having an actual file server and having a computer that just shares files?

Comment: Whatever you want or need it to be. E.g. proper server-grade hardware, or an optimized configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People typically define a file server as a machine that is designed purely for sharing files. Such a machine could be anything, but generally a good file server should aspire to have the following features:

- Minimalist OS
- Minimal overhead software (i.e. little or no virus scan, etc.)
- Automated update / self cleaning / self management features where possible
- Fast hard disk storage
- Redundant storage and / or automated backup
- Fast network connection
- Basic CPU, 2 physical cores at least. Low power preferred.
- Reasonable amount of RAM, enough for OS + operations - The OS will use RAM as a "cache" since traffic from the network can sometimes be significantly faster than a hard drive can read / write
- Uninterruptible power supply
- Low-power consumption components

Such a machine does not need any form of graphical interface (therefore no graphics card or even monitor).

A regular computer does not generally have things like automated backup or even a UPS, and power consumption is much higher because of all of the extra things a regular computer does - graphics, sound, and CPU utilization. etc.